# Angular 4 cli does not load the page without aot flag

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I removed the --aot=true flag from start script inside the package.json, and now i can't load the page, only the default text is there "loading...". When i write back the --aot=true the page works correctly.

I would like to remove the flag, because every rebuild took around 40 - 50 second, which is horrible.

There is no error message or something else.

Is there any suggestion what can cause this problem?

Start script:

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"ng serve --port 4300 --host 0.0.0.0 --hmr=true\"",
```

Comment: You see an error in the js console?

Comment: [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS.. this is the only thing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, there was a wrong order in one of index.ts file.